# What is the formula for the conditional variance when taking the derivative of a Gaussian process?

Tags: variance, covariance, gaussian-process, derivative

The formulae for the conditional mean and variance of a Gaussian process is given by equations [(2.23)](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW.pdf) and [(2.24)](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW.pdf):

[image]

Also, the formula for the covariance of the derivative of a Gaussian process is given by [(9.1)](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW.pdf):

[image]

But what is the formula for the conditional variance of the derivative of a Gaussian process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short Answer**

So the derivative of a Gaussian process is also a Gaussian process with the kernel function equal to that in (9.1). So replace the elements of $K(X_*, X)$ with their evaluation of $\frac{\partial K(X_*, X)}{\partial X_*}$ in equation (2.23) and replace $K(X_*, X_*)$ in equation (2.24) with $\frac{\partial K(a, b)}{\partial a \partial b }$ evaluated at $a=X_*$ and $b = X_*$. Following these two lines after the substitution gives you the expectation and variance of the gradient.

---

**More Details**  [Exerpt from my PhD thesis, talking about quadrature but same difference :P]

(...continuing from the fact that a kernel $K(X_*,X)$ is simply a dot product in a reproducing kernel Hilbert space, $K(X_*,X) = \phi(X_*) \phi(X)^T$)

Another important characteristic of a Gaussian process is that the integrand and differential of a GP is also a GP provided the kernel is integrable and differentiable respectively. This can be easily shown by considering the Hilbert space view of the GP. As,

\begin{equation}
 \begin{split}
  f(x) &= \sum_{i=0}^\infty w_i \phi_i(x), \\
  \int f(x) dx &= \int \sum_{i=0}^\infty w_i \phi_i(x) dx \\
  &= \sum_{i=0}^\infty \int w_i \phi_i(x) dx \\
 \end{split}
\end{equation}

The above integral operator can be replaced with the with differentiation or any other linear operator. Returning to the previous definition of the kernel function we find,

\begin{equation}
 \begin{split}
  \begin{bmatrix}
           \int \phi(\bar{x}) d\bar{x} \\
           \phi(\bar{x} )\\
           \frac{d\phi(\bar{x})}{dx}
         \end{bmatrix} 
         \begin{bmatrix}
           \int \phi(x) dx \\
           \phi(x ) \\
           \frac{d\phi(x)}{dx}
         \end{bmatrix}^T
         &= 
 \begin{bmatrix}
           \int \phi(\bar{x}) d\bar{x} \int \phi(x) dx  & \phi(\bar{x} ) \int \phi(x) dx& \frac{d\phi(\bar{x})}{d\bar{x}}\int \phi(x) dx\\
           \int \phi(\bar{x}) d\bar{x}\phi(x ) & \phi(\bar{x} )\phi(x )& \frac{d\phi(\bar{x})}{d\bar{x}} \phi(x )\\
           \int \phi(\bar{x}) d\bar{x}\frac{d\phi(x)}{dx} & \phi(\bar{x})\frac{d\phi(x)}{dx} & \frac{d\phi(\bar{x})}{d\bar{x}}\frac{d\phi(x)}{dx}
         \end{bmatrix} \\    
&= \begin{bmatrix}
           \int \int K(\bar{x}, x) d\bar{x} dx  & \int K(\bar{x}, x) dx& \int\frac{dK(\bar{x}, x)}{d\bar{x}} dx\\
           \int K(\bar{x}, x) d\bar{x} & K(\bar{x}, x )& \frac{dK(\bar{x}, x)}{d\bar{x}}\\
           \int \frac{K(\bar{x}, x)}{dx} d\bar{x}& \frac{dK(\bar{x}, x)}{dx} & \frac{dK(\bar{x}, x)}{d\bar{x}dx}
         \end{bmatrix}\\
 \end{split}
\end{equation}

This is an interesting result as it means quadrature and gradient observations of the function space can be incorporated into the GP just like any other observation. In a later chapter we will use this principle to create a general framework for fair regression.

Comment: To clarify, is there no derivative taken for $K(X,X)$ in the above formula? Is there only a first derivative on $K(X_*,X)$ and second derivative on $K(X_*,X_*)$? And I agree that a Gaussian process acted upon by a linear operator is also a Gaussian process. But perhaps I am missing the argument here: what's the proof that the (conditional) covariance of this new Gaussian process is given by the formula you described above: $cov(f_*) = \frac{\partial ^2 K(X_*,X_*)}{\partial x_*^2} - \frac{\partial K(X_*,X)}{\partial x_*}[K(X,X) + \sigma^2 I]^{-1} \frac{\partial K(X,X_*)}{\partial x_*}$?

Comment: @Mathews24 exactly you don’t need to differentiate $K(X,X)$. If you want to prove it you start by proving the covariance structure I have shown above and then it is simply a conditional Gaussian distribution, thus it is the difference between the diagonal element (or principal matrix) of the covariance matrix minus the projection of the observation matrix onto that sub space. Basically replace the principal matrix you wish to predict for and the corresponding rows / columns of the covariance matrix connecting that principal matrix and your observations. Hope that is clear :)